# Tornado - How to implement long polling client

Tags: python, comet, tornado, long-polling

I'm trying to implement long pulling client in Tornado, that interacts with an asynchronous Tornado server.

What happens is one of 2 things:

1. Either the client timesout, or
2. The client receives all the messages at once after finishing the
   whole background process, similar to blocking ones

This is the client I use:

```
from tornado import ioloop
from tornado import httpclient

print "\nNon-Blocking AsyncHTTPClient"
import tornado.ioloop

def async_call(response):
        if response.error:
                response.rethrow()
        print "AsyncHTTPClient Response"
        ioloop.IOLoop.instance().stop()

http_client = httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient()
http_client.fetch("http://localhost:9999/text/", async_call)
ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Is this the right way to write a long-polling/comet client?

I would also appreciate for those who will answer to provide a sample async-server in Tornado, because may be I'm writing the cometed Tornado server wrongly... I'm a bit new to the whole long-polling process in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tornado itself has an excellent example of chat, built on top of long-polling mechanism

https://github.com/facebook/tornado/tree/master/demos/chat

It helped me a lot to understand everything, and it have both server and client.

Comment: Thanks cleg for your answer.
The example you provided has only server side implementation with Tornado, while the client-side is in javascript.
I want the client written in Tornado as well, not in javascript, that complies with the long-polling/comet server implementations.

Comment: The client will be a desktop application.

Comment: Well, async polling from Tornado is also pretty simple. Just use Tornado's AsyncHTTPRequest in IOLoop. I've cut example from my project: https://gist.github.com/4370563

Comment: but where is the part in this client where it is expecting parameters to be pushed from the server without a request, except the very first request.
Additionally, when this function gets called:
`def async_request(self, callback, server_url, method=u'GET', body=None, **kwargs):`
And what is callback parameters, and who sets it?

Comment: I'm comaring async request to get and post, where they are called directly when there is get or post request from clients to servers, this is why I ask the above question.

Comment: This is simply request part. When there is no data — this request will wait for data, and if there is any data — it will get them and over. You need to write some kind of loop on top of this function, repeating requests and if there is data — processing it.

Comment: You mean tornado's ioloop add-handler thing, cleg?

Comment: Yes, if you want to work async way, you need to add it to tornado's IOLoop.

Comment: I think you should look some general async programming tutorial, to understand how it's working, what's callback is, etc. http://golubenco.org/2009/09/19/understanding-the-code-inside-tornado-the-asynchronous-web-server-powering-friendfeed/ this is pretty good tutorial, but google have more of them. You can also look some non-python asyn tutorials.

Comment: I really appreciate your help my friend. I have already started doing that and specifically the link you passed, also, I'll consider your other advice and your help as well :)). After all, what I can tell is ... Merry Christmas!! I wish you all the good luck!!

Comment: Just to let you know my friend, I started also looking into Websockets, which is a really better alternative than long-polling http.

Comment: Thank you! Merry Christmas and happy New Year to you too! P.S. Websockets is also good idea.